# Vimeo SDK : Unknown Player Error after Initialization (VueJS)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vimeo

I would like to display a bunch of Videos on a Vue-Website using a Vimeo player.

For this purpose, I created a VideoPlayer-Component which is created for each Video:

```
<template>

  <div class="video-element__container">
    <div class="video-element__player" ref="player" @click="$emit('shrink')"></div>


    <div class="video-element__play-button" @click="play()"></div>
       
  </div>


</template>

<script>
import Player from '@vimeo/player'

export default {
  name: 'VideoPlayer',
  props: ['isActive', 'id'],
  data () {
    return {
      player: null,
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.initPlayer()
  },
  components: {
  },
  methods:
  {
    async play () {
      try {
        await this.player.play()
        this.isPlaying = true
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
      }
    },
    pause() {
      this.player.pause()
      this.isPlaying = false
    },

    initPlayer () {
      let options = {
        url: 'https://vimeo.com/393632283',
        loop: false,
        controls: false,
        muted: true,
      };

      let iframe = this.$refs.player
      this.player = new Player(iframe, options);
    
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

However, whenever I click 'play' I get the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unknown player. Probably unloaded.
    at readyPromise (player.es.js?84c9:1458)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Proxy.ready (player.es.js?84c9:1457)
    at eval (player.es.js?84c9:1311)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Proxy.get (player.es.js?84c9:1306)
    at Proxy.getDuration (player.es.js?84c9:2052)
    at Proxy.initPlayer (VideoPlayer.vue?5912:93)
    at Proxy.play (VideoPlayer.vue?5912:53)
    at Object.onClick._cache.<computed>._cache.<computed> (VideoPlayer.vue?5912:17)
```

Yet, when I use the Vimeo controls it works just fine.
Can someone see the issue here? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Even tho Triet Doan's answer is now accepted, I do not like it. It takes whole OP code written in Options API and rewrote it into Composition API without explaining why it is needed...

Well it is NOT needed at all! In fact, simplest thing to fix original code is to comment out `player: null` in `data()` (as can be seen in demo below)

### Why

Vue reactivity can be a little intruding. Both getters/setters created with [Object.defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) (used for reactivity in Vue 2) and [proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) (used for reactivity in Vue 3) can change the behavior especially for complex data types/classes as Vimeo Player is.

To workaround such problems, just do not put such complex objects into `data()` or do not wrap them in `ref()` or `reactive()`. In most cases you don't need your Vue template to be reactive to some internal state of such complex objects anyway....

Instead just add them to the instance as `this.player = new ...` in `mounted` hook or declare them as ordinary variables (without `ref()` or `reactive()`) in `setup()`

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  name: 'VideoPlayer',
  data() {
    return {
      // player: null, <-- THIS LITTLE CHANGE IS NEEDED
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.initPlayer()
  },
  methods: {
    async play() {
      try {
        await this.player.play()
        this.isPlaying = true
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
      }
    },
    pause() {
      this.player.pause()
      this.isPlaying = false
    },

    initPlayer() {
      let options = {
        url: 'https://vimeo.com/393632283',
        loop: false,
        controls: false,
        muted: true,
      };

      let element = this.$refs.player
      this.player = new Vimeo.Player(element, options);

    }
  }
})
app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.2/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="video-element__container">
    <div class="video-element__player" ref="player" @click="$emit('shrink')"></div>
    <div class="video-element__play-button" @click="play()"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Warning

On the other hand, **I completely agree** with the suggestion of using [existing wrapper - vue-vimeo-player](https://github.com/dobromir-hristov/vue-vimeo-player/blob/next/src/VimeoPlayer.vue). Because it handles some edge cases and more importantly the [unloading of the player when the component is destroyed](https://github.com/dobromir-hristov/vue-vimeo-player/blob/524d6706cbcf89c10290427066cf2fb47f68e21b/src/VimeoPlayer.vue#L123). Without it, you are creating a [memory leak in your app](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/avoiding-memory-leaks.html#Introduction)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I though using the player was not possible without the composition api but this helps a lot! I had to change your code to `new Player` instead `new Vimeo.Player` because of the way I imported the vimeo dependency but not it works perfectly!

Comment: Yes, I had to use `Vimeo.Player` as I'm loading it from CDN - `import` cannot be used in the browser and I wanted my example to work in browser directly without any build step. Glad it helped and hopefully explained also the reason why....

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you're using Vue 3 since your code works perfectly fine for me with Vue 2 and I got the same error with Vue 3.

For Vue 3, you need to restructure your code a bit with the `setup()` method like below:

```js
<template>
  <div class="video-element__container">
    <div class="video-element__player" ref="playerRef" @click="$emit('shrink')"></div>
    <div class="video-element__play-button" @click="play()"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import {ref, onMounted} from 'vue';
import Player from '@vimeo/player';

export default {
  name: 'VideoPlayer',
  setup() {
    let player;
    let isPlaying = false;
    const playerRef = ref(null);

    onMounted(() => {
      const options = {
        url: 'https://vimeo.com/393632283',
        loop: false,
        controls: false,
        muted: true,
      };

      player = new Player(playerRef.value, options);
    });

    const play = () => {
      player.play()
          .then(isPlaying = true)
          .catch(e => console.log(e));
    };

    const pause = () => {
      player.pause()
      isPlaying = false
    };

    return {
      player, isPlaying, playerRef, play, pause
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The code above was already tested and worked as expected.

You can take a look at [Template Refs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-template-refs.html) for more information how to access HTML element inside `setup()`. Regarding the `setup()` method itself, please check the [Composition API](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-introduction.html) documentation.

Besides, there are also some Vue wrapper for the Vimeo SDK, e.g. [`vue-vimeo-player`](https://github.com/dobromir-hristov/vue-vimeo-player). If you want to, you can use them instead of writing your own.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! It got my code working!